# Tensorflow object detection api extratct box feature

Tags: object-detection-api, tensorflow-slim

I am trying to extract bounding box feature from `Tensorflow` object detection API with pretrained model '`faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28`', and trying to extract `topK` bounding box features.

Tensor with the name '`SecondStageBoxPredictor/AvgPool:0`' give me box feature to be (100,1,1,2048), ''`detection_boxes:0`' is bounding boxes coordinates, 'detection_scores:0' is scores

The last two appear to be sorted (Descending as '`detection_scores:0`'), so is the bounding box feature also sorted?